# Alternative attachment to concrete floor containing pex heat tubes

Tags: walls, basement, heating, pex

I am getting ready to finish my basement.  The counties "Typical Finished Basement Details" say that bottom plate attachment to floor is with 16D concrete nails face nailed.  What are USBC approved methods of attaching the bottom plate.  I really worry about putting nails 2" into the floor.

Has anyone any experience with dodging the pipe or alternate attachment?  The heating pex in the concrete is operational and should be in heating mode when I start the project.  Would one of those Infrared detectors work to locate and avoid the pipe?

Comment: I'd ask the local inspector if they'll let you use construction adhesive.  As long as the concrete is clean and dry it's stronger than shooting fasteners into the slab and has a 0% chance of creating a radiant heat disaster.

Comment: Agreed. One of the cheap infrared cameras would help out if you needed to fasten in places here and there. If the plate creeps from the original place you set it, it could be really bad. I have also set plates solely in construction adhesive. Toenail plates together where they intersect and chalk line for BOTH sides of the plate so if one gets covered you can see it happening by the other line being exposed.

Comment: @Comintern - my plan is to talk to the inspector tomorrow, I want to go prepared with options, and questions.  I will ask about construction adhesive.